# C++ - Writing to a specific output window pane in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write to a custom Output Window Pane, but the only examples that I can find for writing to the output window automatically write to the Debug pane.
I've gotten as far as creating a custom pane with a VS add-in in C#, and writing text to it when VS2010 starts up. I'm working in a C++ project, and I'm just wondering how I can write to my custom pane from anywhere in code. I'd like to do it with as little overhead as possible, because I am working in a larger code base that I don't want to have to heavily modify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Debug pane shows results of OutputDebugString calls (either direct, or by `Debug.WriteLine` / `Trace.WriteLine`) (it serves the same purpose as `dbgview.exe` from SysInternals). This is default behavior of the IDE. I think, that writing to custom pane may require implementing your own extension for Visual Studio.

As a workaround, you may use `dbgview`, define specific prefixes (as [MODULE-A]: , [MODULE-B]: etc.) and set filters to highlight occurences of specific words. Note, that dbgview will work properly only if you run your program without the IDE.